# Display LESS.js errors on remote server

Tags: javascript, less

I am developing a website on a remote server using the JS compiler for LESS.

This compiler seems to only display error messages when viewing the site locally. However, when connecting from a remote location the error is not displayed.

While I appreciate the reason behind this I am wondering if less.js can be configured to always display its error messages.

Cheers!

Comment: I just had a look in the less.js file and noticed that the adding of the error message depends on the d.env var being set to 'development'. Further down there's a bit that sets that property to 'development' if location.hostname indicates localhost. By changing this to always be true errors will always display.

Comment: cool! add this as an answer and mark as answered.

Comment: Didn't have the privilege to do that yet but sorted it out now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a look in the less.js file and noticed that the adding of the error message depends on the d.env var being set to 'development'. Further down there's a bit that sets that property to 'development' if location.hostname indicates localhost. By changing this to always be true, errors will always display.

Answer (score -1):

Search for

```
0||f?"development":"development"),
```

and make it like

```
1||f?"development":"development"),
```

Errors will now appear.
Worked for me.

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two lines.